# Parse value(authData) undefined, does not equal nil? It is both nil and not nil

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

This is weird. I am trying to fetch the "authData" value from PFUser.
The logged in username is "Rob"
I can see it from Parse that, the user Rob, has the value undefined for the key "authData".

When i run this code it logs:

---

Rob

nil

authData is not nil

---

So it is both nil and not nil at the same time. What the?? Why? I only have one user named "Rob".

```
var query = PFUser.query()
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {                
            println(PFUser.currentUser().username)

            for object in objects {

             let authData = object["authData"]
                println(authData)
                if authData != nil{
                    println("authdata is not nil")
                }
                else if authData == nil {
                    println("authData is nil")
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

the PFUser's username is nil, so when you do println(PFUser.currentUser().username) this is the first "nil" and the second one is from your else if block.